# Google Oauth2 failing on Google Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, oauth-2.0

Salutations all!

I purchased a Google Domain to make my app slightly more professional than just a bare Herokuapp.  I'm running into issues with Oauth2 on that particular branch of the site.

I'm running rails on the back and a bit of react on the front.

I'm not sure what all you'll need, but I'll start with some bits of code and see what comes up.

The Oauth2 works just fine on the herokuapp portion and on localhost.

**The error (redirect_uri_mismatch)**

[image]

**My authorized redirect URIs**
[image]

Again, attempting to login with google on either Localhost or on Heroku works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma `,` after your specified domain name.

It's showing up as:

```
http://www.stitchinti.me/users/auth/google_oauth2_callback,
```

It should be

```
http://www.stitchinti.me/users/auth/google_oauth2_callback
```

Comment: I clearly need to clean off my monitor.  Thank you kindly.